# TMUX RVM MAC OS X very wiered error

Tags: terminal, tmux

when i run tmux in terminal getting the following error

> __rvm_remove_from_path:8: regex matching error: illegal byte sequence
>   __rvm_remove_from_path:8: regex matching error: illegal byte sequence

Any ideas about this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you might have some weird character in your shell `PATH`. Perhaps a bad Unicode value. Check your `PATH`, and consider piping it through `od` to see if there are hidden weird characters or nulls or something: `echo $PATH | od -c`.

Comment: Thank you Jim Stewart - Your tip solved my problem thanks a lot

Comment: @VarunKumarRaoPonugoti can you post the answer for this.. I am facing the same issue..